# objective-c : only last value iterated in for-each loop is displayed in the label

Tags: objective-c, foreach

Name count i get after parsing `json` is random i.e. it can display any number of values ranging from 1 to 100. I created that many number of labels as shown in the code below, but only the last iterated value is displayed in the `label` when i pass `NSString *name` to `putLabelsInScrollView` method. Can any one help me out to fix this logic to display different name in different created labels?  I cannot create `tableview` which would have been easy and will rectify the `cGRects` of label and `textfields` later.

```
int i = 0;  
            for(NSDictionary *myJsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
            {
                //UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[arrayLabel objectAtIndex:i++];
                //[label setText:myJsonDictionary[@"Name"]];
                NSUserDefaults *defaultNames = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                NSString *name = myJsonDictionary[@"Name"];
                [defaultNames setObject:name forKey:@"QUESTIONNAME"];
                NSLog(@"Value is %@ \n", name);                    
                i++;
            }
            NSLog(@"Number of cycles in for-each = %d", i);
            [self putLabelsInScrollView:i];

- (void) putLabelsInScrollView:(int)numberOfLables
{

        for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfLables ; i++)
        {
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPosition_label, 261, 30)];
            [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0f]];
            label.numberOfLines = 2;
            NSUserDefaults *defaultNameFetch = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSString *fetchedString = [defaultNameFetch objectForKey:@"QUESTIONNAME"];
            [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fetchedString]];
            //[label setText:myJsonDictionary[@"Name"]];

            [self.scroll addSubview:label];
            yPosition_label += 80;

            UITextField *text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPosition_text, 261, 30)];
            text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            text.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            text.delegate = self;
            [self.scroll addSubview:text];
            yPosition_text += 100;
            yPosition_result = yPosition_label + yPosition_text;
        }
        [self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scroll.frame.size.width, yPosition_result)];
        [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Try this...

```
        for(NSDictionary *myJsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
        {
            NSString *name = myJsonDictionary[@"Name"];
            [self putLabelsInScrollView:name];
            NSLog(@"Value is %@ \n", name);                    
        }

        [self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scroll.frame.size.width, yPosition_result)];
        [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];


       - (void) putLabelsInScrollView:(NSString *)labelText
        {


          UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPosition_label, 261, 30)];
          [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0f]];
          label.numberOfLines = 2;
          [label setText:labelText];
          //[label setText:myJsonDictionary[@"Name"]];

          [self.scroll addSubview:label];
          yPosition_label += 80;

          UITextField *text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPosition_text, 261, 30)];
          text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
          text.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
          text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
          text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
          text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
          text.delegate = self;
          [self.scroll addSubview:text];
          yPosition_text += 100;
          yPosition_result = yPosition_label + yPosition_text;

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

Fetching results:

```
int i = 0;
    NSMutableArray *texts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *myJsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
    {
        //UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[arrayLabel objectAtIndex:i++];
        //[label setText:myJsonDictionary[@"Name"]];
        NSUserDefaults *defaultNames = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *name = myJsonDictionary[@"Name"];
        [texts addObject:name];
        NSLog(@"Value is %@ \n", name);
        i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"Number of cycles in for-each = %d", i);
    [self putLabelsInScrollView:i withTexts:texts];
```

And method for putting labels' texts

```
- (void) putLabelsInScrollView:(int)numberOfLables  withTexts:(NSArray *)texts
{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfLables ; i++)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPosition_label, 261, 30)];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0f]];
        label.numberOfLines = 2;
        NSUserDefaults *defaultNameFetch = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *fetchedString = texts[i];
        [label setText:fetchedString];
        //[label setText:myJsonDictionary[@"Name"]];

        [self.scroll addSubview:label];
        yPosition_label += 80;

        UITextField *text = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, yPosition_text, 261, 30)];
        text.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        text.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        text.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        text.delegate = self;
        [self.scroll addSubview:text];
        yPosition_text += 100;
        yPosition_result = yPosition_label + yPosition_text;
    }
    [self.scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scroll.frame.size.width, yPosition_result)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scroll];
}
```